# static private variables not working in c++

Tags: c++, static

I can't understand why static private variable is not working in my code! Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class KittyCat{
private:
int a;
string t;
static int count;
public:
KittyCat(){
    a=0;
    t="NULL";
    count++;
}
void set(int i, string m){
    a=i;
    t=m;
}
void show(){
    cout << "A is: "<< a <<" T is: " << t <<"\n\n";
}
void totalCount(){
    cout <<"Total Counts: "<< count <<"\n\n";
}

};
void main(){
KittyCat tech, review, article, photo, video;
tech.set(10, "Technology");
review.set(85, "Reviews");
article.set(54, "Articles");
article.show();
article.totalCount();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do public static variables work for you when used like this?

Comment: you first need to initialize the static variable.
 int KittyCat::count=0;

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) "not working", it's better to say what behavior you expected, and what behavior you observed.

Comment: @Navin, no, the 'count' is initialized to 0 by default.

Comment: You've *declared* `count`, but you've never *defined* it. Add a line like `int KittyCat::count;` after the definition of `KittCat`, but before `main`.

Comment: @user1764961 not initialized but define. like Jerry Coffin mentioned

Comment: @Navin, for the second time, the static variable is initialized to 0 by default!

Comment: @user1764961 thats what i said... the word "initialize" i mentioned is wrong and it should be "define". Like jerry's examples.

Comment: @Navin, no offense, but based on what you wrote, it seems like you still think it's necessary to explicitly assign zero to the 'count'. And that is NOT true.

Comment: What I meant by my first comment is, if you think `private` has anything to do with it, try `public`. That will help you narrow down your problem.

Comment: @user1764961 yes it's not necessary to initialize it to 0, my mistake. but definitely need to define the static variable. in my first comment i defined and initialized it to 0 because it's a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Even int KittyCat::count; would have also worked. The default value of a static data member is 0. A static data member is declared within the class but defined outside the class definition.

Answer (score -1):

```
int KittyCat::count = 0;
```

must be added before main,because all static data member must be initialized before use.

Comment: Initializing is a good idea, but given the discussion in the comments to the question, you could have thought about this answer a bit more.

Answer (score -3):

Got this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class KittyCat{
private:
int a;
string t;
static int count;
public:
KittyCat(){
    a=0;
    t="NULL";
    count++;
}
void set(int i, string m){
    a=i;
    t=m;
}
void show(){
    cout << "A is: "<< a <<" T is: " << t <<"\n\n";
}
void totalCount(){
    cout <<"Total Counts: "<< count <<"\n\n";
}

};
int KittyCat::count=0;
void main(){
KittyCat tech, review, article, photo, video;
tech.set(10, "Technology");
review.set(85, "Reviews");
article.set(54, "Articles");
article.totalCount();
}
```

Comment: What's this supposed to be? Will you at least explain what the problem was? And could you comment on whether your problem is the same as that described by the possible duplicate question?

Comment: Program ran and reported `Total Counts: 5`.  Looks good to me.  What were your expectations?  What was "not working" for you?

Comment: That is not the proper way to answer a question, especially if it's your own.